# How to initialize sub-collections along with aggregate root in abp.io

Tags: domain-driven-design, abp

What I want to achieve is to figure out where to initialize my sub-collections with aggregate root itself and validate business rules in a best practice way.

Here is my AppService:

```
public async Task<ReservationDto> CreateReservationAsync(CreateReservationInputDto input)
    {
        var reservation = await _reservationSystemManager.CreateAsync(
            input.ReserverNotes
        );

        //should i send them directly to manager's createasync method but RequestedItems  are dto objects.  
        //should i iterate through RequestedItems here and send them to manager one by one.
        // where to throw business exception if RequestedItems count is 0.
    }
```

Here is my inputdto:

```
public class CreateReservationInputDto
{
    public string ReserverNotes { get; set; }

    public Enum.Status Status { get; set; }

    public List<CreateReservationItemInputDto> RequestedItems { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my aggregate root:

```
public class Reservation : FullAuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>
{
    public Enum.Status Status { get; private set; }

    public string ReserverNote { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<ReservationItem> ReservationItems { get; set; }

    public ICollection<OverduePayment> OverduePayments { get; set; }

    private Reservation() { }

    internal Reservation(
        Guid id,
        Enum.Status status,
        [NotNull] string reserverNote,
        ) : base(id)
    {
        ReserverNote = reserverNote;
        Status = status;

        ReservationItems = new Collection<ReservationItem>();
        OverduePayments = new Collection<OverduePayment>();
    }

    //I could not decide where and how to call this function from Domain Service.  
    internal void AddReservationItem(ReservationItem reservationItem)
    {
        if (ReservationItems.Any(r => r.Id == reservationItem.Id))
        {
            return;
        }

        ReservationItems.Add(reservationItem);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends on your business rules and your use cases. For example, if a reservation must have some reservation items, then I would create it in reservation constructor. Otherwise, if after creating reservation I can add new reservation items then I would be another use case and then AddReservationItem has sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you need to inject more than one service (E.g. IUserRepository and IReservationItemsRepository) for validating your collection or any other property, you can create a [domain service](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Domain-Services) and implement your business logic and validate your collection with your needs.

If you don't need to inject any service to implement your business rules you can do it directly in your application service methods. In such cases, you can use data annotations for validating your properties in DTO classes as stated in [here](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Validation#validating-dtos).

> //should i send them directly to manager's createasync method but RequestedItems  are dto objects.
> //should i iterate through RequestedItems here and send them to manager one by one.
> //where to throw business exception if RequestedItems count is 0.

In these three questions you've asked, should take it separately.

- For instance, If you create a [domain service](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Domain-Services) class, it could be better to throw an exception if the **RequestedItems** count is 0 in that class' method. (And you can call, your **AddReservationItem** method from the domain service's method in that case.)

You can also check the [best-practices](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Best-Practices/Index) documents of ABP.